# Can not resolve parseInt in mapToInt function java 8

Tags: java, java-8

In this tutorial page http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/, when I write

```
 Stream.of("a1", "a2", "a3")
.map(s -> s.substring(1))
.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
.max()
.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Nothing happens to my program. But when I try to make a function that can calculate the sum of generic list like this

```
public static <E> int calculateSum(List<E> list) {
  int n = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
  return n;
}
```

The program is built with error by the compiler **Can not resolve method parseInt**

Please help me find the exact cause, and solution for this.

Comment: Why does this method take a `List<E>`? What if `E` is `Dog`? How do you `parseInt` a `Dog`?

Comment: What do you mean with “Nothing happens to my program”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not guaranteed in any way, shape or form that `E` is a `String`.

You can *mask* this by adding a map to `String`...

```
list.stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .sum();
```

...but you're putting a bandage over a gaping wound, since like before, you're not guaranteed that any of your strings are parseable as ints.  By adding the conversion to `String`... the compiler can't help you anymore.

The main issue is that your list should only ever contain `Integer` values before you can sum them.  Better yet, it should only contain `Number`s.

```
public static <E extends Number> int calculateSum(List<E> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .mapToInt(Number::intValue)
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: Such a clear explanation and good solution. It helps me resolve the problem. With this generic function, I can calculate the sum regardless the type of numbers is double, long or integer etc

Comment: @MrDan:  Be careful.  This ignores decimal places.  If you want to keep track of those, you'll have to write your own accumulator.

Comment: You don’t even need a type parameter here. Just change the parameter to `List<? extends Number> list`.